# How To Lower Flash Content's Graphical Quality?

Tags: browser, adobe-flash

I know this is possible but in Hotmail on the right side when i clicked on flash animation, i did not see any quality related controls:

[image]

How can i enable content quality controls in flash content's options?

Answer (score 3):

The Flash developer can change the contents of the option menu (the menu shown above). If he/she removes the quality choice, you really don't have any recourse.

Then again, I know of no real reason to use that setting. It almost never makes a difference in either appearance or speed.

If you want to just avoid delays due to the Flash, use the FlashBlock addon for Firefox or Chrome.

Comment: Maybe Firefox has addon that allows to change settings?